# Java logger (of doom!), updated

Tags: java, file, logging, file-structure

In a previous question, [Java logger (of doom!)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/261338/java-logger-of-doom), I had posted my own logger, written in Java. I have since taken the answers from that question and a few of my own things to update it.

New code:

````
/*
 * Syml, a free and open source programming language.
 * Copyright (C) 2021 William Nelson
 * mailto: catboardbeta AT gmail DOT com
 * Syml is free software, licensed under MIT license. See LICENSE
 * for more information.
 *
 * Syml is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
 */

package personal.williamnelson;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Logger implements Closeable {

    public File logfile = new File("");

    protected FileOutputStream fos;
    protected OutputStreamWriter osw;

    protected DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"); // example: 2021/27/5 12:07:23

    public void init(File fileToLog) {
        try {
            logfile = fileToLog;

            if (fileToLog.exists()) {
                clearFile(fileToLog);
            } else {
                if(!fileToLog.createNewFile()) {
                    System.out.println("An unrecognized error occurred while creating the logfile.");
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) { //NOSONAR
            System.out.println("An error occurred while creating a logfile. Are you sure that '" +
                                logfile.toString() + 
                               "' is a valid filename?"); 
            System.exit(1);
        }
        
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(fileToLog, true);
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            clearFile(fileToLog);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An unrecognized error occurred while start logging stream and " +
                               "writing to log stream, despite passing all tests.");
        }

    }

    public void log(Object o, int logType) throws IOException {
        // logType should be 0 = INFO, 1 = WARN, 2 = ERROR, 3 = FATAL
        osw.write(getTime() + ": ");
        printErrorType(logType);
        osw.write(o.toString() + '\n');
    }

    public void log(int i, int logType) throws IOException {
        osw.write(getTime() + ": ");
        printErrorType(logType);
        osw.write(String.valueOf(i) + '\n');
    }

    private String getTime() {
        LocalDateTime ldtNow = LocalDateTime.now();
        return ldtNow.format(dtf);
    }

    private void clearFile(File file) throws IOException {
        FileOutputStream fosClearer = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
        OutputStreamWriter oswClearer = new OutputStreamWriter(fosClearer);
        oswClearer.write("");
        oswClearer.close();
    }

    private void printErrorType(int errorType) throws IOException {
        switch (errorType) {
            case 0:
                osw.write("INFO: ");
                break;
            case 1:
                osw.write("WARN: ");
                break;
            case 2:
                osw.write("ERROR: ");
                break;
            case 3:
                osw.write("FATAL: ");
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter 'logType  " +
                        "of 'personal.williamnelson.Logger.log'" +
                        " must be one of the following: \n" +
                        "    0: INFO\n" +
                        "    1: WARN\n" +
                        "    2: ERROR\n" +
                        "    3: FATAL\n");
        }
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        osw.close();
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 3):

Why use an `int` to indicate the log type when you can just use an `enum`
That way, you could just write the enum to the `OutputStreamWriter` directly (while avoiding the worry of receiving an incorrect logType: `IllegalArgumentException`):

```java
public class Logger implements Closeable {
  public enum LogType {
    FATAL, ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE;
  }
  ...
  public void log(Object o, LogType logType) throws IOException {
    osw.write(getTime() + ": " + logType + ": " + o.toString() + "\n");
  }
}
```

Also, you could just rewrite the `log(int, LogType)` method to reuse `log(Object, LogType)`, to avoid duplicated code:

```java
public void log(int i, LogType logType) throws IOException {
  log(Integer.valueOf(i), logType);
}
```

Regarding code style, there is no need to write an if-else-if this way:

```java
if (foo) {
  doSomething();
} else {
  if (bar) {
    doSomethingElse();
  }
}
```

Unless you wished to do something in the `else` block, but outside the inner `if`, it is more readable to write it as such:

```java
if (foo) {
  doSomething();
} else if (bar) {
  doSomethingElse();
}
```

Comment: I never would have even thought to use an enum, and I totally forgot about DEBUG and TRACE. Also, where did I use a strange if statement like that?

Comment: @catboardbeta In you `init` method

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your `init()` function and your `try/catch` blocks, shouldn't it be better to use `System.err.println` instead of `System.out.println` when you catch an `IOException`?

On the same lines, if this is supposed to be a generic class, shouldn't the consumer be doing the error handling? You should just hand them the `IOException` (add a `throws IOException` to your `init()` function and remove your `try/catch` blocks) and then force the consumer to handle it instead. This way the consumer has more control on what happens if something wrong happens.

---

Also, what is that extra `log(int i, int logType)` doing there? Shouldn't `int` get boxed into `log(Object o, int logType)`?

On the topic of that, you should definitely use `enums` ([as @m-alorda said](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/261553/243229)). It makes your code much easier to read and use.

Answer (score 2):

- Is there a reason `logfile` can't be an argument of the constructor? The way I see it, a `Logger` that hasn't had `init()` called is just guaranteed to be in an invalid state and entirely useless until `init`ed, so calling `init` in the constructor just seems like a good way to guarantee the `Logger` is in a useful state. Am I missing something?
- I can imagine a situation where some application may want to run part of its code even though the logging isn't working, but since `init` calls `System.exit()` that doesn't seem to even be an option. Unless there's some particular reason `init` (or the `Logger` constructor) must never be allowed to throw exceptions, it should probably do that, rather than `System.exit()`
- It feels a bit weird that `clearFile` can clear files other than the designated `logfile`. Especially since `logfile` is the only file that's ever passed to it, not that a logger should ever want to work with any other files anyway. Wouldn't it make more sense to just have it operate on the log file directly since a logger shouldn't really need to touch any other files anyway?